# Discrete time Integral of a value in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery, m, integral, discretization

I have an Excel table named *CA-27* loaded from an Power Query script.

*CA-27* contains a *decimal* type column named *Q*, representing a flow rate. It also contains a *time* type column named *Time* with YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss data.

I need to run an additional step in Power Query to add a column named *V* with cumulative volume values. I need a formula to calculate a discrete integral of Q over Time to create column *V*. The formula needs to implement the trapezoidal method for discrete integration.

I know how to write formulas directly in excel cells to implement the discrete integration but I want to create the cumulative volume within Power Query, so I can process additional data using the same Power Query steps.

NOTE: Assume the last step previously used to query CA-27 is called *previousStep*.

I first tried the  following M-language syntax to create column *V* within Power Query:

`List.Accumulate(#"previousStep"[Q], 0,(state, current) => state + current         Duration.TotalSeconds([#"CA-27.Time"] - List.First(#"previousStep"[#"CA-27.Time"])))`

I expected to get the cumulative volume but I got the following error message:  "Expression.Error: There is an unknown identifier".

Then I tried this alternative M-language sytnax:

`let Source = previousStep, Integrated = List.Accumulate(Source[Q],0,(state, current) => state + current * Duration.TotalSeconds([CA-27.Time] - List.First(Source[CA-27.Time])) ) in Integrated`

This alternatuve syntax got the following error message: "Expression.SyntaxError: Token Comma expected"

[image: Desired Results Example]

**Trapezoid rule for discrete integrals:**

The first data row, index=(k-1), has no defined Delta_T and V=0.
For the second row onward, range(k) = [2:N], calculations are defined as:

```
Delta_T(k) = [Time(k) - Time(k-1)]; \\ (unit is seconds)

V(k) = 0.5 * [Q(k) + Q(k-1)] *  Delta_T(k); \\ (unit is cubic meters)
```

I've edited the M language code per @horseyride's suggestions as follows:

```
    = let Source = #"Renamed Time",
//offset by 1 row
    MinusOne = #table({"Column1"}, {{null}}) & Table.Skip(Table.DemoteHeaders(Table.RemoveLastN(#"Renamed Time",1)),1),
    custom1 = Table.ToColumns(#"Renamed Time") & Table.ToColumns(MinusOne ),
    custom2 = Table.FromColumns(custom1,Table.ColumnNames(#"Renamed Time")&List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(#"Renamed Time"), each _&"prior")),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(custom2, "Custom", each Duration.TotalSeconds([Time]-[Timeprior])*.5*([Qg_dh]+[Qg_dhprior])),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Added Custom", "IndexDT", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Cum Total" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Vg_dh", each List.Sum(List.FirstN(#"Added Index"[Custom],[IndexDT]+1))),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Cum Total",{"Timeprior", "Qg_dhprior", "Custom", "IndexDT"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

However, processing per this additional query step following the *Rename Time* step appears to result in an infinite loop, or at least an unusually long processing time for a simple cumulative result.

After waiting several minutes I got this error message:

> Expression.Error: Evaluation ran out of memory and can't continue.

Comment: [#"CA-27.Time"] is not going to work unless that is literally the name of one of your columns. This is not how you refer to the time column of the CA-27 Table.  Beyond that I'm personally lost with the calculation you want to make since you didn't provide any sample input data or desired output

Comment: @horseyride Thank you for your input. Should I use [CA-27.Time] to refer to the Time column of table CA-27?

Comment: If you are IN the CA-27 Query, then its just Source[Time]  but if you are in another query then it is #"CA-27"[Time]    (but I don't think that's going to help)

Comment: @horseyride CA-27.Time was merged into the query from the original CA-27 table. So it seems the Source[Time] syntax is what I'll need. I've added sample input and output data per your suggestion above. Thanks.

Comment: @horseyride. Thanks. I've added mathematical expressions for data rows **k = [2 : n]**, and  clarification about values for first data row **k = 1**.

Comment: @horseyride I'll try the code you posted 17-JUL-2023 ASAP. Thanks.

Comment: @horseyride The table I have already has a *Time* column of type *datetime* . Also i have already used previous Query steps. The last step is called  *Renamed Columns* so it seems like I need  to use  <let  Source = #"Renamed Columns">. However this result in an added column  that contain a table in each row instead of a numeric  value for *V*.

Comment: Remove my first two steps and use your last step name place of #"Changed Type" in all my subsequent steps

Comment: @horseyride I tried to follow your latest suggestion. The syntax of the M code passes the  checks its but execution seems to go into a loop and eventually resulted in a memory limit error. See my latest edits to the question. Please advise. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry I'm giving up here. I have no idea what the data looks like in your source and I'm moving on. My sample code works your sample data and I'll have to leave it at that

Comment: @horseyride Sorry, my full data table and earlier query steps contains proprietary information I can't share. I do appreciate your helpful sample solution, and will try to keep working out it's implementation within my full table. Thank you.

Comment: I actually never understood that response.  Data is proprietary? Then change it slightly so its not. How would I know? Code being proprietary though, thats a new one on me.

Comment: @horseyride Sorry about the confusion. Only the data is proprietary. I modified the variable names to avoid disclosure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to post sample data as numbers, not images

That said, try

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Time", type datetime}}),
//offset by 1 row
    MinusOne = #table({"Column1"}, {{null}}) & Table.Skip(Table.DemoteHeaders(Table.RemoveLastN(#"Changed Type",1)),1),
    custom1 = Table.ToColumns(#"Changed Type") & Table.ToColumns(MinusOne ),
    custom2 = Table.FromColumns(custom1,Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type")&List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"), each _&"prior")),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(custom2, "Custom", each Duration.TotalSeconds([Time]-[Timeprior])*.5*([Q]+[Qprior])),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Added Custom", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Cum Total" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "V", each List.Sum(List.FirstN(#"Added Index"[Custom],[Index]+1))),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Cum Total",{"Timeprior", "Qprior", "Custom", "Index"}),
#"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",{{"Time", type datetime}})
in  #"Changed Type2"
```

[image]